# AWS lambda destination not triggering

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

[My current Lambda Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4X0lE.png)

My `child lambda` in destination not triggering by `Main Lambda`. It only triggers when i use `--invocation-type Event` in aws cli. It is not triggering when testing or in live mode. Main lambda works fine in both ways, but it just not triggers destination lambda without cli command.

Full aws cli that works.(But i won't use aws-cli to trigger. It should be triggered by Cloudfront)

`aws lambda invoke --function-name main-lambda --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --payload '{"test": 15}' --invocation-type Event response.json`

**Main Lambda**

```js
const https = require("https");

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    await post("https://example.com/notify", {
    type: "viewer-response",
    event,
    context,});

  let response = "";
  try {
    response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
  } catch (e) {
    response = event; //For debug purposes
  }

  // Added this, but not working either.
  //response.headers['x-amz-invocation-type'] = [{key: 'X-Amz-Invocation-Type', value: 'Event'}];
  return response;
};
```

**Child Lambda**

```js
const https = require('https');

exports.handler = async (event,context,callback) => {

    console.log("Triggered Child Lambda");
    await post("https://example.com/notify", {
          type: "onSuccess-response",
          event,
          context, });

  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
  };
  return response; // I don't need this. This comes from base
}
```

I understand that `Main Lambda` should be invoked with `Event` type because it needs to be async in order to call destination lambda but i can't be able to find a way to do it. I tried adding Environment variables to lambda function but it didn't worked either.

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behaviour.  CloudFront invokes Lambdas using the synchronous [invocation mode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/invocation-modes.html).  The service waits for a response from the Lambda.  Destinations are ignored.

Comment: So you are saying it is impossible.? Is there any workarounds or other services i can use or techniques? But why they allow us to add destination lambdas then.

Comment: You can't choose a invocation mode.  The calling service determines that.  Your alternatives depend on your use case.

Comment: After a successfull response served to a user, i need to send a notification, containing info about served data. This is my use case in this scenario.

Comment: You could use the SDK to post a notification from `Main Lambda`, although this would slow down the response to the client.  Alternatively, consider consuming CloudFront's [request logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/logging.html#logging-requests) to move the notification step off the critical client response path.